# String index out of range when working with String Builder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

So I do get this type of error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   447

Every time when I run this code:

```
String text = "What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    StringBuilder textSb = new StringBuilder(text);
    int textLength = textSb.length();
    System.out.println(textLength);
    for(int i = 3; i< textLength; i += 4){
        if (textSb.charAt(i) == ' '){
            textSb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            i--;
        }else{
            textSb.deleteCharAt(i);
            i--;
        }
```

Ok. So what it want to do. I do try to remove every time looping the fourth character and if it is a space, I delete the second character after the space. I tried to "i--" because the text gets smaller with one character at a time which will mean that my index will not work as I keep deleting those characters.

The main problem is that error. How it's possible to 447 no be in range considering that it have around 597 characters into my string.

Comment: You never recalculate `textLength` and yet you remove characters...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried to make textlength++ and is the same error. Does the for gets it’s text lenght only once?

Comment: What is the point of this exercise?  What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Just modify the for-loop to be `for(int i = 3; i< textSb.length(); i += 4)` and the result should look like `Wha is orm Isum Loem psu is...`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I expect something like this “Wha is orem.....”

Comment: You may want to check if `i+1` is less than `textLength` before you do `textSb.deleteCharAt(i+1);`. You could add the check in the existing `if` condition itself: `if (textSb.charAt(i) == ' ' && i+1<textLength)`. Another issue is you need to reassign the value of `textLength` when you have deleted a character like Elliott has mentioned. Add `textLength = textSb.length();` after each delete statement.

Comment: Thanks @MathewsMathai I have got it right, now.

Comment: Adding the comment as answer if you would like to accept and close it. And you are welcome :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The 477 is because you deleted the rest of the indexes. just check before deleting the index like

```
if (textSb.charAt(i) == ' ' && (i+1<textLength)){
            textSb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After having modified the length of the original string (textSb) but using the original length of the string, it's not surprising you'd got a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Look this example: https://github.com/lombocska/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/main/java/string_index_out_of_range/StringBuilderTestClass.java#L35

```
for (int i = 3; i < textSb.length(); i += 4) {
  ...
}
```

`The answer is that you should use the modified text length in the for cycle instead of the unmodified one.` :)

Answer (score 0):

textSb.deleteCharAt(i); is the culprit. You should not delete from the same StringBuilder rather create a copy of it and then do the operations on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check if `i+1` is less than `textLength`(need to be reassigned after every delete statement as shown in 2) or `textSb.length()` before you
   do `textSb.deleteCharAt(i+1);`.

   You could add the check in the existing `if` condition itself:

   ```
        if (textSb.charAt(i) == ' ' && i+1<textLength)
   ```

   OR

   ```
        if (textSb.charAt(i) == ' ' && i+1<textSb.length())
   ```

---

2. You also need to reassign the value of `textLength` when you delete
   a character like Elliott has mentioned.

   - Add `textLength = textSb.length();` after each delete statement.

   OR

   - change `for loop` to `for(int i = 3; i< textSb.length(); i += 4)`